# use of promise.all to download the images using rn-fetch-blob?

Tags: javascript, rn-fetch-blob

```
  downloadImagesInParallel = async (url) => {
      const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
      reactotron.log('downloadImagesInParallel', url)
       await RNFetchBlob.config({
              appendExt : 'png',
              path : dirs.DocumentDir + `/${url}`
            }).fetch('GET', `${url}`, {
              //some headers ..
            })
    }
```

```
 let newsImageUrl = []
      newsData.forEach(element => {
          newsImageUrl.push(this.downloadImagesInParallel(element.urlToImage).then((data) => {
            reactotron.log('data', data)
          }))
      });
      // const newsImagesURL = newsData.map((item) => this.downloadImagesInParallel(item.urlToImage))
      reactotron.log('setHomeNewsList  ***************** ', newsImageUrl)
      const allData = await Promise.all(newsImageUrl)
```

This is how i tried to download all the images together but i am unable to do it. Please help me out in this.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that is not happening?

Comment: Try logging `allData` instead of `newsImageUrl`?

Comment: Notice that your `downloadImagesInParallel` is misnamed. It downloads a *single* image, and there's nothing parallel about it.

Comment: I want that i download all the images together using promise.all . How can i achieve that ?

Comment: Your code is a bit weird but looks like it would work. Does it not?